# Google app engine static file handlers example

Tags: python, google-app-engine

The [static_dir](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Static_Directory_Handlers) examples are pretty clear

So for example, I want requests to `http://mysite.appengine.com/main.htm` to go to the `C:\<appenginesiteroot>\html\main.htm` file (on the hard disk), and this can be achieved with

```
# app.yaml
- url: /
  static_dir: html
```

But when it comes to [using static file handlers](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Static_File_Handlers) its not clear.

Specifically I want to map a URL *to an html or other static file*.

So for example, requests for `http://mysite.appengine.com/` will send down `main.htm`.

```
- url: /
  script: main.htm ?? #fails because main.htm isn't a script file
```

I know it is possible using a directive like:

```
- url: /
  script: main.py
```

Then having main.py simply send down html, but I'd like to know if "static file handlers" are really in GAE or if its just a hoax.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`script` is for scripts, you are trying to map to a static file.  Have you looked at the [Static File Pattern Handlers](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Static_File_Pattern_Handlers) section of the doc?

Have you tried:

```
- url: /
  static_files: main.html
  upload: main.html
```

Comment: Thanks. Was just having this same problem. Out of curiosity, why is `upload` there/required?